# How do I remove mounted drives from the unity launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, mount, drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove launcher drive icons?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195988/how-to-remove-launcher-drive-icons)

In 11.10 how do I go about removing the mounted drives icons on the Unity Launcher?

This article:
http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/how-to-remove-mounted-drives-from.html
does not work, the only option under *desktop ➜ unity ➜ devices* is `favorites:[]`.

Comment: @RickGreen how can it be a duplicate of something that was posted after this?