# Don't show removable media in the launcher?

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove mounted drives from the unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62011/how-do-i-remove-mounted-drives-from-the-unity-launcher)

Is it possible to disable or remove the icons for removable media, such as DVD drives or external hard drives, from the launcher in 12.04?